# Parsing JPA Annotation

Tags: reverse-engineering, rascal

Can I use Rascal to parse JPA annotations from a Java file? Like the one below

```
@Entity
public class Customers {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Id
    @Column(name = "CustomerID", nullable = false)
    private Integer customerId;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "CustomerName", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String customerName;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "ContactName", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String contactName;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Address", nullable = true, length = 50)
    private String address;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "City", nullable = true, length = 20)
    private String city;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "PostalCode", nullable = true, length = 10)
    private String postalCode;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "Country", nullable = true, length = 15)
    private String country;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customersByCustomerId")
    private Collection<Orders> ordersByCustomerId;

    .....

}
```

I have succeeded in parsing the file with Rascal's *createM3FromFile* and *createAstFromFile* but am not sure how to traverse it to extract the annotations.